# How do I Automate Keeping my TortoiseSVN Project Up-to-date?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, autorun

I am using TortoiseSVN for my Subversion repository held on a USB drive. When I move from one PC to another, is there a way to automatically identify that files are out of date (without using the Check for Modifications menu). It would be nice just to be able to see that the folder on my hard drive did not match that of the repository, rather than seeing the green tick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try creating a file called ["autorun.inf"](http://dailycupoftech.com/usb-drive-autoruninf-tweaking/) in the root directory of your USB key. Then fill it with the following lines:

```
[autorun]
open=CheckForMods.bat
```

Then create a `CheckForMods.bat` batch file in the root directory that does an `svn status -u`.

Comment: This will work if autorun is enabled for the particular drive letter the USB key is assigned to. After too many viral infections thru that vector, I decided to disable autorun on **all** drives, for both work and home PCs - way safer, and I don't miss the *functionality* (too risky, anyway).

Comment: The command "svn status -u" doesn't mean anything if you only have TortoiseSVN. I guess the asker knew that since they already marked this as accepted but in case anyone else was unclear: You also need to get a Windows command-line interface for SVN (which is good to have anyway) in addition to TortoiseSVN: http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download/ is the one I use though there may be others.

Answer (score 1):

Create a batch file which automatically update your local working copy when the USB key is connected.

Comment: How do you trigger a batch file to run on usb key insert?

Comment: CDMenuPro has been developed for you to create impressive Autorun CD menu applications for use on CD ROMs, DVDs and USB Flash Drives without any previous programming knowledge

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/commitmonitor/

Commit Monitor, it has a portable version you can stick on your USB drive